# Different option than Dictionary

Tags: c#, reflection, dictionary, switch-statement, memory-footprint

I made a program that is at its heart is a keyboard hook. I press a specific button and it performs a specific action. Since there is a fairly large list of options that I can select from using a Combobox, I decided to make a Dictionary called ECCMDS (stands for embedded controller commands). I can then set my Combobox items to ECCMDS.Keys and select by a command by name. Makes for easy saving too because its a string I just save it to a XML file. Well the program monitors anywhere from 4-8 buttons. The problem comes from runtime. The program uses about 53 megs of memory (of course I look over at it now and it says 16 megs :/) Well the tablet that this is running on has 3Gb's of memory and a Atom processor. Normally i'd scoff at 53megs, but using a huge switch statement and the program uses about 2 or 3 megs (been sometime since I actually looked at its usage, so I can't remember exactly)

So although the Dictionary greatly reduces the complexity of my RunCommand method I'm wondering about the memory usage. This tablet at idle is using 80% of its memory, so I'd like to make as little of impact on that as possible. Is there another solution to this problem? Here is a small example of the dictionary

```
        ECCMDS = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
        {
            {"Decrease Backlight", EC.DescreaseBrightness},
            {"Increase Backlight", EC.IncreaseBrightness},

            {"Toggle WiFi",  new Action(delegate{EC.WirelessState = GetToggledState(EC.WirelessState);})},
            {"Enable WiFi",  new Action(delegate{EC.WirelessState = ObjectState.Enabled;})},
            {"Disable WiFi", new Action(delegate{EC.WirelessState = ObjectState.Disabled;})},
            {"{PRINTSCRN}", new Action(delegate{VKeys.User32Input.DoPressRawKey(0x2C);})},
        };
```

is it possible to use reflection or something to achieve this?

***EDIT***

So after the nice suggestion of making a new program and comparing the 2 methods I've determained that it is not my Dictionary. I didn't think that WPF was that big of a difference between Winforms, but it must be. The new program doesn't hardly have any pictures (like it used to, most of my graphics are generated now) but the results are as follows

```
Main Entry Point:32356 kb

Before Huge Dictionary:33724 kb
After Initialization:35732 kb
After 10000 runs:37824 kb
That took 932ms to run
After Huge Dictionary:38444 kb

Before Huge Switch Statement:39060 kb
After Initialization:39696 kb
After 10000 runs:40076 kb
That took 1136ms to run
After Huge Switch Statement:40388 kb
```

Comment: enums and a switch statement maybe.

Comment: I can't possibly see how a dictionary with 4-8 items in it is several dozen megs of memory, given that the keys and values are both just references....

Comment: @Servy OP says that what he shows in the post is just a sample of the actual Dictionary.

Comment: Have to agree with Servy on that point it will not make a big differences.

Comment: I suggest you extract the Dictonary to a separate program and see how much space it occupies before you worry about how much space it is taking and if that is your problem.

Comment: @N4TKD The previous programmer had a huge switch statement before and it was so horrible to read that code that I wanted a cleaner solution. I looked around and one solution that seemed like the way to go was to make a Dictionary, so I did.

Comment: @ChuckSavage I like your idea, I am going to give it a shot and see what happens. I must have been too close to the problem to see such a simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: @ChuckSavage Well you were right. It wasn't my problem. Thank you for your helpful tip.

Comment: Switch : 40mb-39mb = 1.3mb done in 1.1 seconds. Dictionary 38mb - 33mb = 4.7mb done in 932ms. Not much of a difference is there huh?

Comment: Robert I entered my comment as an answer so you can accept and close out this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you extract the Dictonary to a separate program and see how much space it occupies before you worry about how much space it is taking and if that is your problem.